# Automatically load model on each request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-5

**Note**: Not sure if the following is the right way of doing what I want.

**Background:** I have a forum (php) and I am creating a asp.net MVC web application that is sort of independent from the forum, except the login data. The user registers and logins through the forum but the app needs to check the login status by reading the session hash from the cookie and comparing it with the forum's database of logged in users.

**Objective:** I to include my UserModel class on every request to see if the user has certain permissions to do what he's requesting to do. Also for my views to display User related data.

Do I need to manually add something like this to every controller's action in my application?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository();
        UserModel user = userRep.GetUserBySession(Request.Cookies["userHash"].Value);

        //do stuff with user 
        ...

        return View(myViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `ValidationAttribute`. You can roll your own, and have your own custom logic in it:

```
public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository();
        UserModel user = userRep.GetUserBySession(Request.Cookies["userHash"].Value);

        if (user == null) { 
            // Redirect to login?
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can decorate your methods like this:

```
[CustomAttribute]
public ActionResult Index()
```

Or if you will be needing to apply it to every HTTP method in your class, you can decorate it at class level:

```
[CustomAttribute]
public class MyClass
```

Comment: Thank you, cut can I then access `UserModel user` inside the decorated methods? Or do I still need to load it "manually"?

Comment: @Cornwell You would still load it manually, but no reason why you couldn't create a user service and call a method that will return the user so you don't have to repeat the same code